# Python hierarchical clustering visualization dump [scipy]

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

Recently I was visualizing my datasets using python modules scikit and scipy **hierarchical** clustering and dendrogram. Dendrogram method drawing me a graph and now I need to export this tree as a graph in my code. I am wondering is there any way to get this data. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that scipy had it's own built in function to turn linkage matrix to binary tree. The function name is scipy.to_tree(matrix)